# How do I render a blazer component on the server and get the generated HTML?

Tags: blazor

I've created a blazor component that renders an SVG graph in my Blazor WASM application. I was wondering how/if I could reuse that component on the server to render its HTML.

[I am currently generating HTML using the razor view engine and converting the HTML into a PDF document](https://www.kambu.pl/blog/how-to-generate-pdf-from-html-in-net-core-applications/). I intend to put the HTML from the blazor component into the view and turn it into a PDF.

Comment: Try this one: https://benjaminvertonghen.medium.com/printing-pdfs-in-blazor-8dff559101f9

Comment: @NicolaBiada That isn't helpful.

Comment: Can't you just use the component tag helper to put it in the view?

Comment: @MisterMagoo yup, that works and is much easier

Answer (score 1):

Mister Magoo pointed me towards a better method.
Simply use the [component tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/component-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in the view.

```
<component type="typeof(MyComponent)" render-mode="Static" param-MyComponentParameter="Model.MyComponentParameter" />
```

---

Old answer:

I managed to figure out the basics and made an extension method.

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Renders the HTML of the blazor component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="httpContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<string> RenderComponentAsync<T>(this HttpContext httpContext) where T : IComponent
    {
        var componentTagHelper = new ComponentTagHelper
        {
            ComponentType = typeof(T),
            RenderMode = RenderMode.Static,
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>(), //TODO: Overload and pass in parameters
            ViewContext = new ViewContext { HttpContext = httpContext },
        };

        var tagHelperContext = new TagHelperContext(
            new TagHelperAttributeList(),
            new Dictionary<object, object>(),
            "uniqueid");

        var tagHelperOutput = new TagHelperOutput(
            "tagName",
            new TagHelperAttributeList(),
            (useCachedResult, encoder) => Task.FromResult<TagHelperContent>(new DefaultTagHelperContent()));

        await componentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(tagHelperContext, tagHelperOutput);

        using var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        tagHelperOutput.Content.WriteTo(stringWriter, HtmlEncoder.Default);

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```